# Трафик из VirtualBox через SOCKS5

Tags: linux, virtualbox, iptables

Linux Ubuntu - хост машина

Сеть > тип подключения > NAT

Как весь трафик **VirtualBox** пропустить через **socks5**?

Например, я создал socks5:

```
# ssh -N -D 777 root@222.222.222.222
```

SOCKS5: **127.0.0.1:777**

Надо, чтобы ip **222.222.222.222** у гостевой ОС был как родной.

Знаю, что надо делать что-то с `iptables`, сетевыми мостами. Но так и не понял.

---

`proxychaines` тоже не помогает.

```
$ proxychaines virtualbox
```

ip у гостевой ОС такой что и у хост машины.

Comment: А через `tsocks` пробовал?

Comment: нет, не получается тоже